# Can not figure out why loop runs twice

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

This seems to be a no brainer, and should not be all that complicated but after two days I'm at wits end. I can not figure out why this loop runs twice.

```js
db = openDatabase("com.xyz.mobile.db", "", "The App Database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM somedata", [], function(tx, result) {
                c = (result.rows.length - 1); //result.rows.length = 2 there are only 2 records
                console.log("c = " + c); // outputs 1 in console
                for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log("i = " + i); 
                    console.log(result.rows.item(i)['description']);
                    if(i == c){
                        console.log("I will run twice just to make you pound on key board");
                        break;
                    } 
                } 
            }, null);
        });
```

Here is what I get in the Chrome console:

```
c = 1
i = 0
2/30/2012 22:02:08
i = 1
2/30/2012 22:02:27
I will run twice just to make you pound on key board
c = 1
i = 0
2/30/2012 22:02:08
i = 1
2/30/2012 22:02:27
I will run twice just to make you pound on key board
```

Help me Obi Wan your my only hope.

Comment: How is that code called?

Comment: So you're not really asking *"why loop runs twice"*. What you actually want to know is why the *callback* runs twice. Right?

Comment: You are checking `if(i==c)` on every loop. For performance I would loop by `i<len-1` and then after the loop finish, do the stuff I want to do with the last item accessing it via the `i`

Comment: The loop is actually placed in the beginning of the body of the webpage, so that it runs when the page is loaded. Inside the loop I had originally placed a jquery method to append a list with the data that is being pulled from the local sql database. I noticed the data was being added multiple times which is why I added the line of code to break. Even then it seems that when I run the code it runs twice or at least outputs the data twice. I cant figure out why that is happening. If notice in the output the line "I will run..." is outputed twice which is just before the break statement.

Comment: Apparently the body was being loaded twice. It looks like it may have been jQuery that was causing this behavior since after I removed the links to jQuery I got the results I expected. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

`c = 1` therefore `result.rows.length = 2` therefore `for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)` runs 2x, i think you meant: `for(var i = 0; i < c; i++)`

unless you were asking why the callback runs twice, in which case I would conclude that it is being called twice...

and I would do:

```
db = openDatabase("com.xyz.mobile.db", "", "The App Database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
console.log('i am here at ' + new Date());
db.transaction(function(tx) {
....
```

Comment: I thought the same thing. The title is poorly worded. OP isn't asking why the loop iterates twice, but instead is asking why the callback runs twice, which makes the loop iterate a total of four times, which makes the `if()`inside the loop run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script is in the

```
<head> </head>
```

section not in the

```
<body> </body>
```

and all things will be fine. A colleague of mine had the same problem, and this was the fix. We still don't have a proper answer why it runs twice but have a go and let me know it this helped.